# Centos 7 missing python-xml package

Tags: python, centos7, yum

I am attempting to install Ambari Server 2.7.1, which depends on python 2.7.  From my understanding, the default Centos 7 Python is 2.7.5, which "should" be fine, but when I go to install the Ambari Server using yum, it fails stating:

"Error: Package: ambari-server-2.7.1.0-169.x86_64 (ambari-2.7.1.0) Requires: python-xml".

When I search the yum repos I have installed (Base, CR, Debuginfo, Fasttrack, Sources, Vault, EPEL, HDP, HDF, AMBARI, and mysql57-community), I cannot find python-xml anywhere, but from searching google, found that it should be part of base Python 2.7.

I have also tried "yum clean all" and this has no effect on the problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure there will be an acceptable answer to this...I spun up an identical base image on my private Openstack cloud and installed Ambari server with no issues...the only difference I could think of between installs was the order in which I installed components.  For example, I installed Ambari server followed by MySQL the second go-around, whereas I installed MySQL first, the first time I tried it.

I could not find anything in the log files that gave me any clues as to what happened...but I do have both instances running in my cloud in the hopes of troubleshooting it further.